# how to find out the number of cells that are common in segmented image and reference image in matlab

Tags: matlab

I done segmentation of the breast cancer cells with 2 algorithms.the next step is to evaluate the 2 algorithms using sensitivity and positive prediction value.so i count both the no.of cells segmented image and reference with 49 and 27 cells respectively.next i have to find out the no.of cells that are present in reference image and segmented image,no.of cells that are present in reference but not in segmented image and no.of cells that are not in reference but present in segmented image.both the images are gray scale.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is how to give cells identity that will be consistent between different segmentation methods. With your segmentation result, I suppose you can calculate geometric center for each cell in both cases. Starting from reference image, if you're looking for the same cell in the segmented case, search within a certain distance ( e.g 1/2 of a cell's maximum length ) of each cell's geometric center and see if there's any cell in the segmented case whose geometric center falls within this range. Then you have your count. It'd be better if you post your codes here so answers can be more specific.

Comment: sensitivity and positive prediction value  is same as precision and recall.

Comment: i trying to find out matlab code for sensitivity and positive prediction value.sensitivity=tp/(tp+fn).then how to write the code for tp,fp,fn.the definitions for tp is no.of nuclei which have been marked by the experts and also detected by the algoritm,fn is no.of nuclei which have been marked by the experts but are not detected by the algoritm and fp is no.of nuclei which are not marked by the experts but detected by the algoritm.

Comment: It seems to me you're just beginning to learn MATLAB. I think you'll be better off starting with MATLAB documentation.

Comment: tn=0;fp=0;fn=0;tp=0;
     
    tp=sum(gr==1 & ~Seg_Im2==1)
    
    tn=sum(gr==0 & ~Seg_Im2==0)

    fn=sum(gr==1 & ~Seg_Im2==0)

    fp=sum(gr==0 & ~Seg_Im2==1)

ss=tp/(tp+fn);

ppv=tp/(tp+fp);

Comment: i write the above code is it write .gr and ~Seg_Im2 is the reference and segmented image respectively.i refer different research paper and net from that i write it .please help